# Prevent page reloading while submitting item to a cart.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am developing a [shopping cart](http://goo.gl/6Rnpi3) and I need to **prevent page reload when the adding a product to the cart**.

Currently I am using **GET method** to submit the product to the cart

```
<a href="cart/add?itemid=101&itemcat=starter></a>
```

As you can see I am using link tag instead of forms. I tried this code to prevent page reload

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".prod a").click(function(){

        var id = $(".prod").find('input[id=itemid]').val();
        var cat = $(".prod").find('input[id=itemcat]').val();

        alert('ID :' + id + '\n\rCAT :' + cat);
        return false; // reload stopped
    });
});
```

As you may have noticed I have used alert() to test the output is like **I am only getting values of only 1st product rest are ignored** thought of using loop . Please verify the above code or suggest other solution.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zCz4d/4/) * Updated

The problem is i am able to get item id of 1st product not 2nd

Comment: you can use ajax request for that

Comment: It's not an answer to the question but you should really *not* be using GET to add items to carts. The HTTP GET method should never be used for operations which modify server state. In this instance, it should really be a PUT, although a POST wouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [event.preventdefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to stop default  behavior of anchor tag .

You need [this keyword](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

Change

```
var id = $(".prod").find('input[id=itemid]').val();
var cat = $(".prod").find('input[id=itemcat]').val();
```

to

You need closest `tr` element not `.prod`

[ID Selector (“#id”)](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('#itemid').val();
var cat = $(this).closest('tr').find('#itemcat').val();
```

---

[closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

`$(this).closest('tr')` get the closest `tr` element up the `DOM`.

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".prod a").click(function (e) {
        e.PreventDefault(); //to stop default behavior of anchor tag
        //this refers to the current a element clicked .
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('#itemid').val();
        var cat = $(this).closest('tr').find('#itemcat').val();
        alert('ID :' + id + '\n\rCAT :' + cat);
        return false; // reload stopped
    });
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/wG58W/)</kbd>

Comment: Good catch however that won't solve the page reloading, that solves a separate issue.

Comment: @srajelli Check updated answer and demo --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/wG58W/

Comment: @Ian issue is solved  and the issue was because of this keyword only .

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".prod a").click(function(e){

    var id = $(".prod").find('input[id=itemid]').val();
    var cat = $(".prod").find('input[id=itemcat]').val();

    alert('ID :' + id + '\n\rCAT :' + cat);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false; // reload stopped
});
});
```

Try adding `e.PreventDefault()` onto your script.

Answer (score 0):

U use this

```
    $(".prod a").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(".prod").find('input[id=itemid]').val();
        var cat = $(".prod").find('input[id=itemcat]').val();

        alert('ID :' + id + '\n\rCAT :' + cat);
        return false; // reload stopped

    });
```